# DolphinDB: How to deduplicate array vectors while preserving the order of their elements?

Tags: sorting, distinct, dolphindb

I want to deduplicate the column “b“ in the figure below, but the `distinct` function cannot be used with the `group by` or `context by` clause, nor can it preserve the order of the elements. Besides ungrouping the table and deduplicating with the `isDuplicated` function, are there any other methods?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the loop function, as shown in the following script:

```
t = table(`a`b as sym, array(INT[]).append!([1 2 1, 2 3 2]) as val)
// Not preserving the order
select sym, loop(distinct,val) as`val from t 

// Preserving the order
select sym, loop(x -> x[ifirstHit{==,x,}:E(distinct x).sort()], val) as `val from t
```